# Problem with lyrics and horizontal alignment of notes in measure

Tags: lilypond

If I have this code :

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "italiano"

solistsMelody = 
  \relative do'' { 
    \time 2/4
    \repeat volta 2 {
    %en las alturas
    <mi, la>8 <mi la>8 si'4\rest
    %paz a los hombres que ama el senor
    si4\rest <mi, mi'>16 <mi mi'>8 <re re'>16 <do do'>8 <la la'>8 
    \tuplet 3/2 {<re re'>8 <si si'>8 <sol sol'>8}
    \bar "||"}

    \alternative {
        {<la la'>4 si'4\rest}
        {<la, la'>4 do'8 do8}
      }
    }

solistsWords = 
  \lyricmode { 
    hom -- bres
      paz a los hom  -- bres que~a -- ma~el -- se -- ñor Te~a -- la --
  }

womenMelody = 
  \relative do' {
    \time 2/4
    \repeat volta 2 {
      si'4\rest
      << 
        { \voiceOne mi16 mi8 re16 do8 la8 mi'4 ~ mi4 }
        \new Voice { 
          \voiceTwo fa,4 ~ fa4 la4 ~ la4 }
      >> \oneVoice
      <fa sol>4 (
    }
    \alternative {
      { <mi la>4) <mi la>8 <mi la>8 }
      { <mi la>4 si4\rest }
    }
  }

womenWords = 
  \lyricmode { 
               paz a los hom -- bres paz __
               Ah __ Glo -- ria~a ah
             }

menMelody =
  \relative do' {
    \clef bass

    \time 2/4

    \repeat volta 2 {
      % paz paz ah gloria a
      <<
        { re,4\rest <re do'>4 ~ <re do'>4 }
        \addlyrics { paz __ }
      >>
      <re do'>4 ~ <re do'>4 <sol, re'>4 (
    }
    \alternative {
      { <la mi>4) <mi la>8 <mi la>8 }
      { <mi la>4 <mi la>8 <mi la>8 }
    }
  }

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff <<

    \new Staff = "solists" \with {
      instrumentName = #"Solist "
    }
    <<
      \new Voice = "solists" {
        \voiceOne
        \solistsMelody
      }
    >>

    \new Lyrics = "solists"

    \context Lyrics = "solists" {
      \lyricsto "solists" {
        \solistsWords
      }
    }

    \new Staff {
      \new Voice = "women" {
        \womenMelody
      }
    }  

    \new Lyrics = "women"

    \new Staff {
      \new Voice = "men" {
        \menMelody
      }
    }

    \context Lyrics = "women" {
      \lyricsto "women" {
        \womenWords
      }
    }
  >>

}
```

[image: Problem 1]

As you can see, after `paz a los hombres` for the women, the `la mi` for women and `re do` for men should be aligned horizontally (because the lyrics are in common here)

So, I wanted to do a minimum example taking off the soloist voice and here's what I got :

[image: Even worse]

It's even worse, the `re do` for men has shifted to the next measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this problem on `2.19.54`, so you might try updating your LilyPond version to fix it.

With that said, I've spotted the culprit in `2.18.2`: if you comment out `\addlyrics { paz __ }`, the music aligns correctly. As such, I recommend using `lyricmode` for `menMelody` like you do for the soloists and women; this should clear up the problem.

Comment: Yep, I noticed the thing about the lyrics but my problem is, in the rest of the score, the men voices have the same lyrics as the women so I don't want to create a `lyricmode` for them (well, I could if I knew how to explicitly append the start of the lyrics to a precise note).

Comment: Thanks for the update tip. I don't like unstable versions that much, usually, but well, it works so... ;-)